# VB.net application crashes without specific error

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I developed one application in VB.Net 2010. It worked fine on my laptop.
Now when I run this on another PC, it just crashes and give windows error as below.

> Application: CallinkMig.exe
>   Framework Version: v4.0.30319
>   Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
>   Exception Info: System.InvalidOperationException
>   Stack:
>      at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.DoApplicationModel()
>      at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run(System.String[])
>      at CallinkMig.My.MyApplication.Main(System.String[])

Along with this.

> EventType clr20r3, P1 callinkmig.exe, P2 1.0.0.0, P3 4cb8209c, P4 mscorlib, P5 4.0.0.0, P6 4ba1da6f, P7 105d, P8 1c, P9 system.invalidoperationexception, P10 NIL.

This application required .Net framework 4 & Oracle 9 ODBC drivers, which I installed on new PC.

I am not able to figure out what is the problem exactly, however it seems something with .Net framework itself

Can anybody please help me?

Comment: @Amid Sharma were you able to sort your problem?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a problem with your code, best way to find out is instal vs2010 on that machine and debug it, if your code is looking at or depending on something residing on the computer, and its a little different on the computer where it crashed, and you are not accounting for this or not expecting it, it will crash.

Or if you don't wanna install vs2010 wrap your code inside some try catch handlers and get the ex.description to display in a message box or something... Let us know how you do!